# Laravel: key rotation - data encryption

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

could someone point out what I'm doing wrong? For security reasons, I have to rotate the application key on a regular basis. This is easily doable, run the `artisan key:generate --force` and you are basically done. However, now I'll have to re-encrypt my encrypted data in the database. I've checked how other public packages are doing it, but I just can't seem to make it work.

The error:

```
The MAC is invalid.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:218
    214▕             throw new DecryptException('The payload is invalid.');
    215▕         }
    216▕ 
    217▕         if (! self::$supportedCiphers[strtolower($this->cipher)]['aead'] && ! $this->validMac($payload)) {
  ➜ 218▕             throw new DecryptException('The MAC is invalid.');
    219▕         }
    220▕ 
    221▕         return $payload;
    222▕     }

      +7 vendor frames 
  8   app/Console/Commands/RotateAppKey.php:116
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save()

  9   app/Console/Commands/RotateAppKey.php:50
      App\Console\Commands\RotateAppKey::reEncryptModelData()
```

Here is a simplified User model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'secret' => 'encrypted',
    ];
}
```

In my custom "re-encrypt" command I get the current APP_KEY from the config, run the `key:generate --force` command, get the new APP_KEY, create two `Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter` instances, decrypt the old value, encrypt it again with the new key, and then I set the now re-encrypted field on the model. So far so good, but when I try to save the model, I get the error as seen above.

The custom command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class RotateAppKey extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'security:rotate-app-key';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Rotates the application key and re-encrypts some sensitive data in the DB.';

    private Encrypter $oldEncrypter;

    private Encrypter $newEncrypter;

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $oldAppKey = $this->laravel['config']['app.key'];

        $this->call('key:generate', ['--force' => true]);

        $this->setup($oldAppKey);

        app(User::class)::chunk(
            500,
            fn (Collection $users) => $users->each(fn (User $u) => $this->reEncryptModelData($u, ['secret']))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Initiate the setup
     * 
     * @param string $oldAppKey
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    private function setup(string $oldAppKey)
    {
        // Get cipher of encryption
        $cipher = $this->laravel['config']['app.cipher'];

        // Get newly generated app_key
        $newAppKey = $this->laravel['config']['app.key'];

        // Verify the keys
        $oldAppKey = (string)$this->normalizeKey($oldAppKey);
        $newAppKey = (string)$this->normalizeKey($newAppKey);

        // Initialize encrypter instance for old app key
        $this->oldEncrypter = $this->getEncrypterInstance($oldAppKey, $cipher);
        $this->newEncrypter = $this->getEncrypterInstance($newAppKey, $cipher);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate Encrypter instance based
     * on key and cipher
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $cipher
     * 
     * @return Encrypter
     */
    private function getEncrypterInstance($key, $cipher)
    {
        return new Encrypter($key, $cipher);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate Encrypter instance based
     * on key and cipher
     * 
     * @param string $key
     * @param string $cipher
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    private function reEncryptModelData(Model $model, array $fields): void
    {
        $attributes = $model->getAttributes();

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            // Neither options works
            // $attributes[$field] = $this->reEncrypt($attributes[$field]);
            $model->{$field} = $this->reEncrypt($attributes[$field]);
        }

        $model->timestamps = false;
        // Neither options works
        // $model->setRawAttributes($attributes);
        $model->save();
    }

    /**
     * Re-encrypt the old encrypted data
     * 
     * @param string $payloadValue
     * @param bool $serialized
     * 
     * @throws DecryptException
     * @return string
     */
    private function reEncrypt($payloadValue, $serialized = false): string
    {
        try {
            return $this->newEncrypter->encrypt($this->oldEncrypter->decrypt($payloadValue, $serialized), $serialized);
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            throw new DecryptException('Either the passed old APP_KEY is incorrect or payload value is invalid!');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decode the APP_KEY
     * 
     * @param string $payloadValue
     * @param bool $serialized
     * 
     * @throws DecryptException
     * @return string
     */
    private function normalizeKey(string $key): string
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($key, 'base64:')) {
            return base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
        }

        return $key;
    }
}
```

It's worth noting, that if I omit the auto-cast on the User model, and use encryptString, decryptString manually with the facade, it works, however, I'd like to avoid creating a mutator and an accessor for each and every encrypted field if possible.

Comment: I don't know if it is helpful in anyway, but at the end of [this article](https://divinglaravel.com/app_key-is-a-secret-heres-what-its-used-for-how-you-can-rotate-it) the author has a link to what appears to be a really simple key rotation strategy.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the article! I've simplified the command by a lot thanks to its gists. I think I came across this once, but couldn't wrap my head around why my tests were still failing, even though the encryption was working. Turns out it was related to app cache... If you create an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I'd be fine with you posting your own answer for how you solved this.